# "The method '[]' was called on null" in flutter app and the data is not getting displayed

Tags: json, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to display data on my flutter app by importing json file in my firebase account but i think there is some error in my code.

```
class MatchList{
  List<MatchListItem> matchList;

  MatchList({this.matchList});

  factory MatchList.fromJSON(Map<dynamic,dynamic> json){
    return MatchList(
      matchList: parsematches(json)
    );
  }

  static List<MatchListItem> parsematches(matchJSON){
    var mList=matchJSON['browseMatches'] as List;
    List<MatchListItem> matchList=mList.map((data) => MatchListItem.fromJson(data)).toList();
    return matchList;
  }
}


class MatchListItem {
  int id;
  String title;
  String match;
  String date;
  String desc;

  MatchListItem({this.id,this.title,this.match,this.date,this.desc});




  factory MatchListItem.fromJson(Map<dynamic,dynamic> parsedJson) {
//    print(parsedJson);

    return MatchListItem(id: parsedJson['index'],title:parsedJson['title'],match: parsedJson['match'],date:parsedJson['date'],desc:parsedJson['desc']);
  }
}
```

This is my matchListModel.dart file

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:nostra_prediction/matchListModel.dart';
import 'dart:async' show Future;

class MakeCall{
  List<MatchListItem> listItems=[];
// ListItem recipeModelList=new ListItem();


  Future<List<MatchListItem>> firebaseCalls (DatabaseReference databaseReference) async{
    MatchList matchList;
        DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = await databaseReference.once();
        Map<dynamic,dynamic> jsonResponse=dataSnapshot.value[0]['content'];
        matchList = new MatchList.fromJSON(jsonResponse);
        print(matchList);
        listItems.addAll(matchList.matchList);
//        for(var i in matchList.matchList){
//          listItems.addAll(matchList.matchList);
//        }
//        print(matchList.matchList[1].foodtitle);
          print('Thatt ${listItems[0].title}');
//        return matchList.matchList;
    return listItems;
    }
  }
```

This is my getMainListInformation.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:nostra_prediction/constants.dart';
import 'package:nostra_prediction/getMainListInformation.dart';



class Matches extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  MatchesList createState()=> MatchesList();
}

class MatchesList extends State<Matches>{
  final color = const Color(0xffbfd6ba);
  final colorText = const Color(0xffd1bad6);
  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  final makecall= new MakeCall();

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var futureBuilder=new FutureBuilder(
      future: makecall.firebaseCalls(databaseReference), // async work
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none: return new Text('Press button to start');
          case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading....');
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            else
              return 
                ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
//                  return new Text(snapshot.data[index].foodtitle);
                   return Card(
                elevation: 0.0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  child:  SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.15,
                       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                       child:  Card(
                           elevation: 0,
                           child: Row(
                             children: <Widget>[
                               
                               Padding(
                                 padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10,right: 5,top: 5),
                                 child: Column(
                                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                   children: <Widget>[
                                     new Container(
                                       child: Column(
                                         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                         children: <Widget>[
                                           Column(
                                             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                             children: <Widget>[
                                               Text(snapshot.data[index].title, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20,fontFamily: 'Roboto-Black'),),
                                               SizedBox(height:10.0),
                                               Row(
                                                 children: <Widget>[
                                                   new IconTheme(
                                                     data: new IconThemeData(
                                                         color: Colors.black26),
                                                     child: new Icon(Icons.timer,size: 20.0,),
                                                   ),
                                                   Text('${snapshot.data[index].match} minutes',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,color: Colors.black26),)
                                                 ],
                                               )

                                             ],
                                           )
                                         ],
                                       ),
                                     ),
//                rightFavFood
                                   ],
                                 ),
                               )
                             ],
                           )
                       )


                   ),
                ),
              );
                },
                );
        }
      },
    );
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: color,
        centerTitle: true,
//        title: Text('Browsing', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto-Black',fontSize: 25,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,color: Colors.black),),
          title : new Image.asset('images/cooking.png'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), color: Colors.black26,onPressed: (){print('Menu pressed');},)
        ],
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),

      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0,bottom: 10),
         color: color,
         child: new Row(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           children: <Widget>[
             ButtonTheme(
               minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.4,
               height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.06,
               child:MaterialButton(
                 onPressed: (){

                   //                 MakeCall makecall= new MakeCall();
//                 var response=makecall.firebaseCalls(databaseReference);
//                 print(makecall.listItems[0].foodtitle);
//                 print(makecall.listItems[1].foodtitle);
//                   new ListView.builder(
//                    itemCount: makecall.listItems.length,
//                     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
//                      return
//                     },
//                   );
                   },
                 color: Colors.white,
//               disabledTextColor: Colors.grey,
               shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(left: Radius.circular(10.0), right: Radius.circular(1.0))
               ),
//                 elevation: 15.0,
                 splashColor: color,
                 highlightColor:color,
//                 highlightElevation: 1.0,
                 child: Text("Cook Book",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto-Thin ',color: Colors.black26,fontSize: 15),),
               ) ,
             ),

             ButtonTheme(
               minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.4,
               height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.06,
               buttonColor: Colors.amberAccent,
               child:MaterialButton(
                 onPressed: (){Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Hey There')));},
                 color: Colors.white,
//               disabledTextColor: Colors.grey,
               shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(right: Radius.circular(10.0), left: Radius.circular(1.0))
               ),
//                 elevation: 15.0,

                 highlightColor:color,
//                 highlightElevation: 1.0,
                 child: Text("Favourite",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto-Thin ',color: Colors.black26,fontSize: 15)),
               ) ,
             ),
           ],
         ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 0),
          new Expanded(
//        
            child:Container(
              child: futureBuilder,
            ) ,
//
          ),

        ],
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: color,
        elevation: 20.0,
        currentIndex: 0,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home,color: Colors.white,),
            title: new Text('Home',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.add_circle,color: Colors.white,),
            title: new Text('Add a Recipe',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.w700))
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.collections,color: Colors.white,),
            title: new Text('My recipes',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
    }
      }
```

this is my body.dart file

```
{
    "json": [{

        "content": {
            "browseMatches": [{
                    "index": 1,
                    "date" : "12/04/12",
                    "desc" : "asdfgh",
                    "match": "abcdefgh",
                    "title": "wxyz"
                }, {
                    "index": 12,
                    "date" : "12/04/12",
                    "desc" : "qwerty",
                    "match": "abcd",
                    "title": "xyz"
                }

            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

And lastly this is my json data.
I have been trying to display this json data in a listview on card but unable to do so.Please help!

the exact message which gets displayed is:

Error:NoSuchMethodFound.The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver:null
Tried calling:

Comment: Can you please post the full stacktrace? There should be much more details about the error e.g. what line the problem has occur.

Comment: Please post the error message for better understanding.